# bxslider nextText/prevText not working in angular17

Tags: angular, slider, bxslider

i am trying to make the controls of bxslide to show fontawesome icons using nextText  and prevText configurations, it appears in console but not in the view. but even when using a normal string.

this is what i have in the component's ts file:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      const slider = ($('#bxslider-home4') as any).bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        nextText: '<fa-icon [icon]="right"></fa-icon>',
        prevText: '<fa-icon [icon]="right"></fa-icon>',

      });
    });
  }
```

fontawesome is handled properly and used normally in another divs inside the html file without problems